# Change class from "collapse" to "collapse in" in menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this left site menu :

```
<ul class="list-group sidebar-nav-v1" id="sidebar-nav">
     <li class="list-group-item list-toggle">                   
           <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse-typography">Typography</a>
           <ul id="collapse-typography" class="collapse">
                  <li><a href="link_1"> Name 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="link_2"> Name 2</a></li>                            
                  <li><a href="link_3"> Name 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="link_4"> Name 4</a></li>
           </ul>
     </li>

    .
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

Adding ( active ) to "li" elements its done :

```
var url = window.location;

$('ul.list-group a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
$('ul.list-group a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
```

Now I only need to change

```
<ul id="collapse-typography" class="collapse">
```

into

```
<ul id="collapse-typography" class="collapse in">
```

Any ideas on how can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below code

```
$('ul.list-group a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
$('ul.list-group a').filter(function () {
  return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active').parents('ul.collapse').addClass('in').parents('li.list-toggle').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks. I have a small fallow up question :
I need <li class="list-group-item list-toggle">  ..... change to  ......
<li class="list-group-item list-toggle active">